# Flutter android_alarm_manager without firebase auth

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm trying to use the Flutter android_alarm_manager to create some background tasks but can't seem to get it working without the firebase auth. I followed the [readme on the plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager), but just adding the `android_alarm_manager` plugin in the `pubspec.yaml` causes the app to crash immediately (emulator and real device) on startup. How can I avoid the Firebase integration and still use the alarm manager plugin?

Comment: I had some difficulties with this as well.
For reference I created the [smallest possible alarm_manager example](https://github.com/marcmo/flutter_alarm_manager_example) that *does not use* a **firebase** integration. This should show you how to avoid the firebase setup.

Comment: what did you do? would you mind explaining it? can't get mine to work!

Comment: Cloning your project works fine, but when i create my own project, register on firebase and all, i get a platformChannel error when `await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize()` is called.

Comment: what do you mean with registering on firebase? the question was how to use the plugin without firebase setup.

Comment: yes, but your pubspec has `firebase_auth` and `google_sign_in` with your `google-service.json` file in your andrioid project. That means the app has already been registered in firebase console. That is what i meant. Will try upgrading my flutter version and see if it will work tough

Comment: shut...you are correct @nonybrighto ... forgot about those...copy paste error! I removed it, those plugins are not necessary at all for alarm_manager!

Comment: ok. Wil check it out again. Thanks

Comment: I was also able to get it to work just using the sample code provided over at https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager, and it doesn't involve any auth.

Answer (score 1):

Re: *`but can't seem to get it working without the firebase auth`*

Maybe at the time of your attempt back in 2018, there was some unintended entangling or some other issue in your app, but as of now, https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager does not require any Firebase.

Just need to set up some permissions, a service, and receivers in the manifest, then this sample is runnable:

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}

main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(...);
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}
```

Also see [/flutter/android_alarm_manager/example/](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_alarm_manager/example)